# Get Ruby class name without class method

Tags: ruby, oop, class, object, ruby-1.9.3

How can I get the class name of an instance of BasicObject in Ruby? For example, say I have this:

```
class MyObjectSystem < BasicObject
end
puts MyObjectSystem.new.class
```

How can I make this code succeed?

EDIT: I've found that Object's instance method `class` is defined as `return rb_class_real(CLASS_OF(obj));`. Any way to use this from Ruby?

Comment: Can you give a slightly more concrete example of what you are trying to do?  Are you asking "If I have a class Foo that inherits from BasicObject, is there a way to identify that an instance of that class is 'Foo' as opposed to BasicObject"?  Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Actually, yes exactly! Changing the post to clarify

Comment: Why can't you use the `#class` method?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek because `#class` is defined on `Object`, not `BasicObject` which my class inherits from (I'm certain I don't want to use Object)

Comment: The point of BasicObject is to *not* have many methods.  Why do you need or want to subclass BasicObject and not Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent some time playing around with irb and came up with this:

```
class BasicObject
  def class
    klass = class << self; self; end # get the object's singleton class
    klass.superclass # the superclass of an object's singleton class is that object's class
  end
end
```

That will give any object that inherits from BasicObject a `#class` method that you can call.

**Edit**

Further explanation as requested in the comments:

Say you have object `obj` that is an instance of class `Foo`. `obj` gets its instance methods from those that are defined within the class `Foo`, in addition to the methods defined in `Foo`'s parent class and so on up the inheritance chain.  Ruby lets you define methods directly on an object that are only accessible to that particular object like this

```
obj = Foo.new
def obj.hello
  puts "hello"
end

obj.hello  #=> hello

other_obj = Foo.new
other_obj.hello  #=> Method missing error
```

The reason you can do this is because every object has something called a singleton class (or sometimes call an eigenclass) that you are actually defining the method on.  This singleton class actually exists in the inheritance chain of the object directly beneath the object's actual class.  That makes the object's actual class, `Foo` in this example, the superclass of the object's singleton class.

The `class << self` line you see in the answer is a special syntax for entering the scope of an object's singleton class.  So in the example above, you could also define a method in an object's singleton class like this

```
class << obj
  def goodbye
    puts "goodbye"
  end
end

obj.goodbye  #=> goodbye
```

So the line `class << self; self; end` is opening the object's singleton class (whatever object is currently `self`) and then returning `self` (`self` has now become the singleton class), which can then be assigned to a variable to do what you wish with.

I would recommend reading [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) if you want a better explanation of all this.  It definitely gives you a much better understanding of the Ruby object model as a whole.

Comment: That's awesome. I'd like to understand why and how that works. Could you provide a more in-depth explanation?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira No problem!  I edited the answer to provided some additional explanation.  It's probably still kind of confusing, but hopefully gives you enough info to dig in and learn more!

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! I'm still having a little trouble understanding just where the singleton class fits in the inheritance tree. Does [this diagram](http://oi39.tinypic.com/66zxn9.jpg) capture the relationships accurately?

Comment: Not quite.  The object inherits directly from its singleton class and the singleton class inherits directly from the object's real class.  It's a simple chain that just looks like: object < object's singleton class < object's real class.  There isn't an actual link between the object and its real class, it simply goes through the singleton class (which is a subclass of the real class).

Comment: Thanks again! I never considered that because [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-class) returns the actual class of the object, even if there is a singleton class in the hierarchy. As described in [this article](http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton), the `class` method [simply skips it](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L158). Man, this changes everything I thought I knew!

Answer (score 1):

I have to leave in a few minutes so I can't test it myself, but it seems like you could make a separate module that uses [ffi](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) to call `rb_class_real` from libruby. If I had more time I would test it first, but nobody else has answered yet and I don't want you leave you totally out in the cold.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into this. Thanks! But do you know of a pure Ruby way? That'd be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jeff Smith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9986347/3558355), you can do this without modifying `BasicObject`:

```
class << object; self; end.superclass
```

where `object` is an instance of an object whose class you want, i.e.,

```
irb(main):001:0> object = BasicObject.new
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=> 
irb(main):002:0> class << object; self; end.superclass
=> BasicObject
```